# I have n number of voice commands which is converted to string and then based on the command the execution takes place

Tags: c#

But the problem is I end up writing a Switch case, resulting in n number of cases for each command. How do I avoid it? Code in c#

Example:

```
switch ()
{
 case "Open File":
  //do something;
  break;
 case "Change color":
 //do something;
 break;
 .
 .
 .
 case n:
 // do smething;
 break;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  What are you trying to *avoid*?  A switch sounds reasonable with the [small amount of] information you gave us.

Comment: if you have a lot of these switches...you could consider a factory pattern perhaps

Comment: @rory.ap: there are more than 200 commands, it not worth to write 200 case . Thats is what i am trying to avoid. Moreover the commands can be of any length , its doesnot follow a specific pattern

Comment: Well then you need to look into writing specialized classes to handle commands and/or categories of commands.  Make use of factory patterns like @Ctznkane525 suggested.  C# is an object-oriented programming language, so make use of that.

Comment: How about using an interface, eg. ICommand, which provides one Method 'Execute()'? You could then avoid the whole switch/case by calling ICommand.Execute(); Or am I completely off track?

Comment: I think your question is a design question. You could get the command and delegate to a script file with the command as file name. Or you could go with reflection (if you want to stay with c#)

Comment: @Oerk : You are right!

Comment: May [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834852/how-to-implement-custom-command-line-execution/50836007#50836007) is of interest.

Comment: @TaW : perfect what i was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'm closing this as a duplicate then, if you don't mind..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap each command in its own handler like this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler
{
    string HandlesCommand { get; }
    void Execute();
}

public class OpenFileCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    public string HandlesCommand => "Open File";
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Open File");
    }
}

public class ChangeColorCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    public string HandlesCommand => "Change Color";
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Change color");
    }
}
```

If you have an IoC container, you can usually inject all the handlers in a class by asking for `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler>`. If you don't have an IoC container, you can put all the handlers in an array like this

```
private ICommandHandler[] _commandHandlers = {new OpenFileCommandHandler(), new ChangeColorCommandHandler()};
```

Then you can find all the handlers for a command and execute them like this

```
var command = "Open File";
var handlers = _commandHandlers.Where(c => c.HandlesCommand == command);
foreach (var handler in handlers)
{
    handler.Execute();
}
```

This also has the advantage that you can add new command handlers without changing any existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wil try it out.